# Does C++ has the ability to use PBKDF2 (OpenSSL)?

Tags: c++, encryption, pbkdf2

I have been looking for a good C++ solution to PBKDF2-encryption. I have OpenSSL installed successfully and can en/decrypt string successfully.

However, I would like to add an extra layer by using PBKDF2-encryption, but so far I can't find a good solution how to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

P.s. I only want to use solid software solutions, such as OpenSSL e.g. so no custom made functions, for security reasons.

Comment: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC.html ?

Comment: Since when is OpenSSL a solid software solution? To me spelling "NSS" or "OpenSSL" is just short for spelling "Buffer Overrun".

Comment: Wow Alex, thanks I looked for this answer for 3 days... My bad.